# Some app fires alarms more then 64(local notification) , any way to manage this?

Tags: ios, push-notification, uilocalnotification

In my app i need to update locally settled alarms with local notifications, after 64 has been fired then set new 64 is remaining even though app is killed by user.
This means it needs to update alarms while app is killed.
In iOS that is not allowed, but
Some applications like Alarmy, Alarm Clock Pro, dozen are doing some what like this.

So is there any way to get this?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. What I've done was to create a queue and on every launch of application I rescheduled notifications based on the queue. 64 can be scheduled and the others are in the queue according to their fire date. I've also created silent push notifications that would arrive every n hour in order to force my app become active. With this approach, I could take care of that queue even if the user doesn't open the app. Your goal can be achieved but it is really difficult to implement.

After all, iOS ecosystem does not let third-party apps that have the same functionality as OS 's default apps to thrive. So basically if you're creating an alarm app you should better think again.

Comment: Thanks, for instant replay.
But with silent notification, if application is killed by user, then how can you manage queue? Because app is killed and user has not done any action on notification then , how to reschedule queue ? Is your app live on App Store?

Comment: Hello @Soroush,
How its possible to force app become active?

Comment: hi, take a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application) @poojsfollowal

Comment: Hello,
But this method didReceiveRemoteNotification is not getting triggred if user killed the app.

Comment: Yes you are right. If the user kills the app (double click home - swipe up), this method will not get called but this is the best shot you can take. I did an exhaustive research on this one and this seems to be the only one working.

Comment: There is a scenario where you've scheduled all 64 notifications and user has killed your app and will not open it even if 64 notifications has triggered. It seems like there is no solution with this one. More like a deadend.

Comment: Right but that 64 notifications are not of the 1 day , I has settled 64 notifications based on user setup of alarms time and repetition.So may be user can get only 10-15 alarms of the day and all that has been cleared from tray only. Actually I am facing issue that my owner has settled lots of alarms , they have got fired alarms till 2-3 days , after that alarm not working, bcz 64 alarms has been fired and he has not opened app once even and not even tapped on notification , directly killed from tray.

Comment: my app is not available on the Appstore since it was made for an organization and was distributed through enterprise program. My app was a reminder-like app so it was unlikely for the user not to open it after 64 notifications. I hope I've been helpful.